# How to mount /boot from LiveCD (FreeBSD 11 ZFS)

Tags: boot, mount, freebsd, zfs, bsd

FreeBSD 11 (current) with ZFS

I can mount `zroot` with `zpool import -fR /mnt zroot`

but `/mnt/boot` is empty (and it's even not a directory)

I need to edit loader.conf, how can I do it?

Comment: Sounds like your `/boot` is on a separate partition. We can't tell you which one unless you [edit] your question and add your partitioning scheme.

Answer (score 1):

3 years too late; but for the record:

There was a bug in the 11 bsd installer which always made /boot a separate zpool named 'bootpool'. This was necessary for encrypted root disks (the kernel and modules had to be left unencrypted); but the bug had the installer doing it regardless of encryption (see: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=212258)

This is also discussed in the FreeBSD forums: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/42980/ and https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/59004/

Answer (score 0):

Please show the partitioning scheme.  Use "gpart show".  You'll probably see a partition of type freebsd-ufs.  The third column (small number) shows which slice it is.  You have the device name above.  For example, if you see "ada0" and "2", connect those two into "ada0p2".